# How to access android camera via usb from PC

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Currently i am researching about USB Camera.

I am looking like USb Camera. I need to access android camera via USB from PC Browser or any application installed in PC.

Is that possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use this: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=usbwebcam.application&hl=en

You need to install soft from http://www.placaware.com/ on your pc too.